# Checkbox won't uncheck from function

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
public void UncheckCheckbox()
{
    checkBox1.Checked = false;
    MessageBox.Show("Unchecked!");
}
```

When i try to uncheck my checkbox with this code it stays the same. Can someone tell me how i can make this work?

**EDIT**

It still doesn't work. The messagebox **does** show up, but the checkBox doesn't change.

**EDIT 2**

When i try to uncheck the checkbox directly with a button (without the function) it does work, but i don't understand why the function doesn't. I tried all of your suggestions but nothing helped me out.

**EDIT 3**

My main form (Form1) is a MDI Container. When Form2 (child) closes, it runs the code that i've showed you earlier. The code that i use for the child is:

```
private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Form1 ParentForm1 = new Form1();
    ParentForm1.UncheckCheckbox();
}
```

I think this won't be a problem, because the checkbox stays checked when i try to run the function from Form1 itself.

Comment: Not enough to go on here.  Is this a Winform app?  Do you have a properly assigned event handler?  Please show more code.

Comment: Does the MessageBox show up?

Comment: how did you call that method?

Comment: UncheckCheckbox should be called from UI thread, or use Invoke/BeginInvoke on checkBox1. for example checkBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => checkBox1.Checked = false));

Comment: Next time you ask a question here on [so], can you be a bit more explicit. You should have provided the code as to where the `UncheckCheckbox();` function was being called from...

Comment: @JeremyThompson I'll do so in the future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Form2_FormClosing event creates a new instance of the parent form and sets the checked value on it instead of the existing parent form you want.

Comment: Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Many ways most of which are readily available on internet. Simplest(dirtiest) is having a reference to an instance of ParentForm asigned on creation of Form2, and then use this reference.

Comment: After a long time of searching on the internet i still don't know how to do this. Can you help me?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1a390803-e987-4806-a2a3-51b989bf1b80/communicating-between-parent-child-forms-in-vbnet?forum=vbgeneral

Answer (score 2):

When you set `Checked = false;` it will call the [CheckedChanged event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checkedchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You must have code in the CheckedChanged event that ticks the checkbox again.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work. Try this.Update(); this should redraw the form.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably calling it from another thread, in which case it won't work.
Search for cross-thread calls and/or invoke controls.